# How to share an image generated within a Facebook App with the new Facebook Share dialog using the Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

Facebook recently deprecated the use of the **Feed** Dialog -
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0
in favour of the new **Share** dialog.

Unlike the Feed dialog, sharing an image with the new Share dialog seems more complicated.
The only useful info is here -
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#photos
However the guide states that **user_generated** is limited to image taken from a *camera* on the user's device. We're developing a Facebook app which allows users to import pictures & then decorate them with text, stickers, etc.

How can we share the *image generated* by the app using the new Share dialog with Javascript SDK?